# I/Choreographer: Skipped 'n' frames! (When using AsyncTask or Thread)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Heyy ! I know there are many questions regarding this topic in StackOverflow and to be honest I have dig pretty much and I'm still getting this issue. It will really be helpful if somebody can point out my mistake as it will save a bunch of my time.

This android application is expected to capture an image from the mobile device and store it in the image view. Later another button will be clicked to perform an image processing and tesseract to display the output in the text view provided.

Everything seems to be working fine from the beginning where no threading or Asyntask were provided to execute the OCR/opencv tasks. The downside of this was "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." and also the screen will go black for awhile until the results is available.

Knowing that I will have to move it to a thread to prevent it from running on the UI itself, I read and watch some tutorials to be able to do it. Now after applying threading and even after applying AsycncTask to the OCR function, I am getting the output, BUT this time, the 'The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.' is occurring whenever I touch anywhere on the application and this is making the whole app to run slow unless I restart it which I don't want to.

Take a look at the Threads and AsyncTask I have implemented(I did not run them both together. I comment them out when I'm running either one of them.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Uri CapturedimagePath;
    Handler ocrResultHandler;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    ArrayList<String> getResultList;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");

    }

       button_performOcr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                /**TESTING FOR THREAD OR ASYNCTASK***/

                imageBitmap = null;
                try {
                    imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), CapturedimagePath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //new AsyncOCRTask().execute(imageBitmap);


                Thread ocrThread = new Thread(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                              getResultList =   runOCR(imageBitmap);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if(getResultList!=null){
                                            testing_textView.setText("");
                                            name_val_txtView.setText("");
                                            address_val_txtView.setText("");

                                            testing_textView_1.setText(getResultList.get(0));
                                            testing_textView_2.setText(getResultList.get(1));
                                            testing_textView_3.setText(getResultList.get(2));
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                ocrThread.start();
            }
        });

        private class AsyncOCRTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, ArrayList<String>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {

                Bitmap imageUri = params[0];
                ArrayList<String> getOCRDataList =   runOCR(imageUri);
                return getOCRDataList;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

            if (arrayList != null){
                testing_textView_1.setText("");
                testing_textView_2.setText("");
                testing_textView_3.setText("");

               testing_textView_1.setText(arrayList.get(0));
                testing_textView_2.setText(arrayList.get(1));
                testing_textView_3.setText(arrayList.get(2));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Image Detected to Process !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> runOCR(Bitmap image) {

        ArrayList<String> imgOCRoutput ;
        if(image != null){
            //Some tesseract and opencv codes to read the image

            imgOCRoutput= new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImages.size(); i++) {
                imgOCRoutput.add(i, mTess.getUTF8Text());
            }
        }
        return imagesResult;
    }
}
```

The message im getting at my Log after the OCR successfully displayed the results and when i click/touch my UI :

```
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.


 /*THIS IS WHEN I CLICK EXCECUTE ANOTHER IMAGE TO READ AFTER SUCCESSFULY GETTING THE RESULT*/



 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage Starting a blocking GC Alloc
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 236(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 149MB/165MB, paused 423us total 7.658ms
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage Starting a blocking GC Alloc
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 295(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(88MB) LOS objects, 20% free, 60MB/76MB, paused 374us total 46.866ms

 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 28304-28304/com.hasomp.topaco.testImage I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The
```

Comment: I think you should use profiling tools to get reason of blocking UI thread.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov how about my thread and my Asyntask that i declared? Am i missing out anything ?